# Arduino String: use a non-null-terminated char array?

Tags: string, convert, data

I'm using a library that takes a `String` as it's parameter (https://github.com/gmag11/painlessMesh)

I want to pass char arrays that is binary (UTF-8) data that also contains null-bytes (`0x00`). Right now, the resulting String is cut off at the first null-byte as expected. I know the full length of the char array, is it possible to construct an Arduino String while passing the arbitrary length, so that the full String also contains the null-bytes including the data that follows after, up until the pre-set length?

I had this problem before and then I solved it by converting the UTF-8 data to hex and then add a null-byte. I was hoping there is a more elegant way, since this forces me to double the data-size.

Thanks!

Comment: A "String" can't have null characters inside it, so why do you need to pass in data that is not a "String"? Is it because you need to send a message payload that is not a "String"?

Comment: The only zero byte the UTF-8 encoding produces is the null character. If the zero byte is anywhere but at the end, then it's not UTF-8.

Comment: @josecanuc I don't want to use a String, it's just that the library asks me to pass one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the function

```
bool painlessMesh::sendBroadcast( String &msg, bool includeSelf = false)
```

Then you'll see that ultimately, the library passes `msg` into the function `buildMeshPackage` where it constructs a JSON message ([see here](https://github.com/gmag11/painlessMesh/blob/master/src/painlessMeshComm.cpp))

```cpp
String ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR painlessMesh::buildMeshPackage(uint32_t destId, uint32_t fromId, meshPackageType type, String &msg) {
    debugMsg(GENERAL, "In buildMeshPackage(): msg=%s\n", msg.c_str());

    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
    JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
    root["dest"] = destId;
    //root["from"] = _nodeId;
    root["from"] = fromId;
    root["type"] = (uint8_t)type;

    switch (type) {
    case NODE_SYNC_REQUEST:
    case NODE_SYNC_REPLY:
    {
        JsonArray& subs = jsonBuffer.parseArray(msg);
        if (!subs.success()) {
            debugMsg(GENERAL, "buildMeshPackage(): subs = jsonBuffer.parseArray( msg ) failed!");
        }
        root["subs"] = subs;
        break;
    }
    case TIME_SYNC:
        root["msg"] = jsonBuffer.parseObject(msg);
        break;
    default:
        root["msg"] = msg;
    }

    String ret;
    root.printTo(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Even if you did construct a `String` with null terminators in it, the moment it gets put into the JSON string it destroys everything. JSON by default doesn't support binary data strings ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443158/binary-data-in-json-string-something-better-than-base64)).

So, the library is a problem because it happily passes data as JSON messages, and that's bad if you want binary data transported. You could use Base64 or the more efficient http://base91.sourceforge.net/ encoding though to mitigate this a little bit, or search for a different lib.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the fast answer. Alright, I guess I have to settle for non-binary then.. Thanks!

Comment: The key part of this answer is to encode your "binary" data. This has been done for ages, and email messages *still* commonly have base64-encoded "text" for binary file attachments. If the framework takes Strings, then you *must* convert your binary data to something that looks like a string.

Comment: I would've upvoted your answer if I could :) (low rep blocks that at the moment)